# Erro: "You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime.Serialization'"

Tags: c#

Estou com este erro:

[image: ERRO]

> The type 'System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject' is
>   defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must adda reference
>   to assembly 'System.Runtime.Serialization,
>   Version=3.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089

Como posso resolvê-lo?

Comment: Copia o texto do erro e cole ele diretamente na pergunta, fica mais facil de visualizar.

Comment: Você já adicionou uma referência ao assembly mencionado no erro?

Comment: Tentei adicionar o "System.Runtime.Serialization" mais não obtive sucesso, diz: Serialization não é uma classe de atributo.

Comment: Como que você está tentando adicionar este assembly? @Vinicius

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você tentou adicionar assim? Eu estava com esse mesmo erro, dai add ela clicando com o botão direito em reference no projeto que estava dando erro e funcionou normal.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]